# React Hooks setState is Updating but View is not

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have a function rentDrone() running on click, through context, everything in it is working and the other 2 pieces of state are updating and updating in the UI, however my stations list is not

```
//React Imports
import React, { FC, useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { Col, Container, Row } from "react-bootstrap";
import _ from "lodash";
//Self Imports
import { RentalPane } from "../../components/RentalPane/RentalPane";
import { Station } from "../../components/Station/Station";
import { RentalContext } from "../RentalContext/RentalContext";
import stationsFile from "../../assets/stations.json";
//Style Imports
import "./App.scss";

//Entry point to the application rendered by index.tsx
export const App: FC = () => {
  // States
  const [rental, setRental] = useState<IRental[]>([
    {
      drone: [],
      isReturning: false,
    },
  ]);
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);
  /* This would normally be an api call with a catch for when the 
  API failed to show the user an error and have a state to show a 
  loading indicator for the user while the data is being fetched 
  */
  const [stationsList, setStationsList] = useState<IStation[]>(
    stationsFile.stations
  );
  // Drone Rental
  const rentDrone = (drone: IDrone) => {
    const updateStations = stationsList?.map((station) => {
      if (station.drones.includes(drone.model)) {
        _.pull(station.drones, drone.model);
        return station;
      } else {
        return station;
      }
    });
    setStationsList(updateStations);
    setRental([
      {
        drone: [drone],
        isReturning: false,
      },
    ]);
    setIsLoading(false);
  };

  const returnDrone = (drone: IDrone) => {
    setIsLoading(true);
  };

  return (
    <RentalContext.Provider
      value={{ isLoading, rental, rentDrone, returnDrone }}
    >
      <div className="App" data-testid="AppContainer">
        <Container>
          <Row className="mt-3">
            <h1>Drone Rentals</h1>
          </Row>
          <Row>
            <Col>
              {stationsList &&
                stationsList.map((station, i) => {
                  return (
                    <Station
                      name={station.name}
                      drones={station.drones}
                      key={i}
                    />
                  );
                })}
            </Col>
            <Col className="d-none d-md-block"></Col>
          </Row>
        </Container>
        {!isLoading && <RentalPane />}
      </div>
    </RentalContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

The Station component has a useEffect to rerun when drones change, if I take this out I can get it to update but then I get the infinite useEffect error in the console.

```
import React, { FC, useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { Row } from "react-bootstrap";
import { Drone } from "../Drone/Drone";
import quadsFile from "../../assets/quads.json";

export const Station: FC<IStation> = ({ name, drones }) => {
  //State
  const [dronesList, setDronesList] = useState<IDrone[]>();
  // Drones

  /* This would normally be an api call with a catch for when the 
  API failed to show the user an error and have a state to show a 
  loading indicator for the user while the data is being fetched 
  */
  useEffect(() => {
    // You would also normally implement a try catch to signal any errors in the non API processing part of fetching dynamic data.

    const fetchDronesList = () => {
      //Get just the drones for this station
      const stationsDrones = quadsFile.quads.filter((drone) => {
        return drones.includes(drone.model);
      });
      setDronesList(stationsDrones);
    };
    // You would also normally implement a try catch to signal any errors in the
    // non API processing part of fetching dynamic data.
    fetchDronesList();
  }, [drones]);

  return (
    <Row className="mb-3">
      <h2>{name}</h2>
      {dronesList &&
        dronesList.map((drone, i) => {
          return <Drone {...drone} key={i} />;
        })}
    </Row>
  );
};
```

Having no dependency array fixes the problem but I get the error in the console

```
Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component calls setState inside useEffect, but useEffect either doesn't have a dependency array, or one of the dependencies changes on every render.
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Perhaps try changing `drones={station.drones}` to `drones={{...station.drones}}` just as a test.

Comment: Don't use ```setDronesList()``` inside useEffect().  Instead filter the drones for the specific station once your component is mounted by setting your useState() to the filter method you have in useEffect()

Comment: @BenStephens that worked but with the array object it is, thank you so much! From what I've learned this is because state does a shallow compare, so if you changed something nested you need to trick it by copying the object instead of passing it.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried use `station.name` instead of the array index for `key`? The `key` prop is the identifier for React to calculate/decide when to re-render, when using the index, since it doesn't change even with `stations` being updated, it's possible some rendering cycles are skipped unexpectedly.

```
{stationsList &&
    stationsList.map((station, i) => {
        return (
            <Station
                name={station.name}
                drones={station.drones}
                key={station.name}
            />
        );
    }
)}
```

When you remove the `deps` array os `useEffect` and inside of it contains code updating state, it becomes an infinite loop of `useEffect()` => `setDronesList(...)` => update UI => `useEffect()`, hence the error.

Comment: Good note on Key didn't know that, did that and it didn't work but changed drone={[...stations.drones]} and it worked!